# how to scroll a page inside a qwebview?

Tags: python, pyqt, qwebview

I guess this should be a simple task: change a QWebView's content (it always contains several pages of stuff) then scroll the page back in the previous position:

```
y = self.webView.page().mainFrame().scrollPosition().y()
self.webView.setHtml(looong_html_text)
if y != 0:
    self.webView.scroll(0, y)
    self.webView.page().mainFrame().scroll(0, y)
    self.webView.page().mainFrame().setScrollPosition(QPoint(0, y))
    print(self.webView.page().mainFrame().scrollPosition().y())
```

But the 3 commands inside the if are completely useless: the page scrolls back to top.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a guess:

setScrollPosition will not let you scroll beyond the end of the page.

Since you are scrolling before the page is displayed, the page's effective height is 0 at the time. You could verify this by checking self.webView.page().mainFrame().contentSize()

Maybe you should do the scrolling when contentSizeChanged is triggered.

Comment: I've placed that particular qwebview in a qscrollarea, but what you said seems reasonable, I will check it out soon with another qwebview. Thank you.

Comment: finally, I tried saving the scroll position before to update the content (self.scrollpos = aWebView.page().mainFrame().scrollPosition()), then restore it in the contentSizeChanged event as suggested (aWebView.page().mainFrame().setScrollPosition(self.scrollpos)). and it works. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
     ui->webView->page()->mainFrame()->scroll(ui->webView->page()->mainFrame()->contentsSize().width(), ui->webView->page()->mainFrame()->contentsSize().height());
```